# noticed when replacing ListView with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Trying to replace the `ListView` with `RecyclerView`.
Not sure if someone also having problem to use `RecyclerView`. I noticed without changing the view item layout, using `RecyclerView` the scrolling is not as smooth as when using `ListView`, and for my view item layout only `GridLayoutManager` works.

Any suggestion? thanks!

The view item layout is not changed and it has been working fine with `ListView` (has > 1000 data).

With `ListView`:

```
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>


public class UsingListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter;

UsingListViewAdapter mAdaptor new UsingListViewAdapter(null, mSelectListener);
    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdaptor);
```

with `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent”/>

public class UsingRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter< UsingRecyclerViewAdapter.RowViewHolder>
                                       implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener;


UsingRecyclerViewAdapter mAdaptor new UsingRecyclerViewAdapter(null, mSelectListener)
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1); 
    //mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());  

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaptor);
```

The view item used in the `Adapter`s of `ListView` and `RecyclerView` are same layout, which one row has two elements side by side using layout_width=“0dp"/layout_weight=“1” to stretch to fill the row.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:visibility="gone"
    >
    <include
            android:id="@+id/row_cell_one"
            layout="@layout/cell_layout" 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <include
            android:id="@+id/row_cell_two"
            layout="@layout/cell_layout" 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The cell_layout is like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/img_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/dumy_img" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overlay_img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/box_border"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/overlay_image"
        android:tint="@color/dark_pink"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/right"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/right"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Both (using `ListView` or `RecyclerView`) have similar `Adapter` to update the `View`, 
except in `RecyclerView` implemented

```
public RowViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
public void onBindViewHolder(RowViewHolder holder, int position) 
public int getItemCount()
```

1. First notice is the the scrolling of using `ListView` is much much smoother than using the `RecyclerView`.
2. If use `LinearLayoutManager`, the items displayed in the row are messed up. The two items do not occupy full width of the display, and the element supposed to be overlay on top of other element (e.g `img.top == overlay_img.top`) is placed below (e.g. `overlay_img.top == img.top + img.height`), and with same height of white space below the `overlay_img`.

Only after changed to use `mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);` then the row is properly displayed.

with `RecyclerView` (using `LinearLayoutManager`) it is displayed as:

```
+---------------------+

(cell | (cell  
 one) |  two)

+---------------------+
```

With `ListView` and `RecyclerView` (using `GridLayoutManager`) it is displayed as:

```
+---------------------+

(cell one) | (cell two)

+---------------------+
```

Comment: when run on device with Android os 4..4.2 and below feel the difference at scrolling, when run on Nexus 5 with Lollipop it feels same smoothness as using ListView.